# QML Scroll Bar doesn't update when it is at the bottom and window height is resized

Tags: qt, qml

I have a custom scrollbar QML type that I am working on. The problem I'm having is that if the scroll bar is all the way at the bottom of the page and the height of the main application window is increased, the translated contents stay in place and the size of the scroll bar is not updated. After this window resize occurs, clicking on the scroll bar causes the content to snap to its proper place and the scroll bar to snap to its proper size. What changes might could be made to the code below so the position of the contents (red blocks) and scroll bar size update while the window height is changing? Not afterwards when the scroll bar has been clicked again. To see the issue just open the code below, scroll the blue scroll bar all the way to the bottom, increase the height of the main window (observing the scroll bar size and the content position), and then click on the scroll bar after the resize. Here is my code:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15


Window {
    id: main_window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: 'light blue'

    // container
    ColumnLayout {
        id: my_column
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: main_window.width / 3
        height: main_window.height / 3
        spacing: 0

        // contents
        ColumnLayout {
            id: repeater_element
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: false
            spacing: 4
            Repeater {
                model: 7
                Rectangle {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 75
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                    color: 'red'
                }
            }
            transform: Translate {
                id: rect_translate
                y: 0
            }
        }
    }

    // scroll bar type
    Scroll_Bar {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        height: parent.height
        width: 20
        container_element: my_column
        content_element: repeater_element
        translate_element: rect_translate
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
    }

    // just a border for the container element
    Shape {
        ShapePath {
            strokeWidth: 4
            strokeColor: "black"
            fillColor: Qt.rgba(.09, .05, .86, 0)
            joinStyle: ShapePath.MiterJoin
            startX: my_column.x
            startY: my_column.y

            PathLine {
                relativeX: my_column.width
                relativeY: 0
            }

            PathLine {
                relativeX: 0
                relativeY: my_column.height
            }

            PathLine {
                relativeX: -my_column.width
                relativeY: 0
            }

            PathLine {
                relativeX: 0
                relativeY: -my_column.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Scroll_Bar.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ScrollBar {
    property var container_element
    property var content_element
    property var translate_element

    QtObject {
        id: internal
        property real vertical_size: container_element.height / content_element.height
        property real horizontal_size: container_element.width / content_element.width
        property real off_the_bottom: (content_element.height - container_element.height) + translate_element.y
    }

    id: scroll_bar_element
    hoverEnabled: true
    active: size
    orientation: orientation
    size: orientation === Qt.Vertical ? internal.vertical_size : internal.horizontal_size
    padding: 0
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        id: ci
        radius: 0
        color: 'blue'
    }

    onSizeChanged: {
        if(size > 1){
            visible = false
        }
        else{
            visible = true
        }
    }

    onPositionChanged: {
        if (orientation === Qt.Horizontal) {
            translate_element.x = -scroll_bar_element.position * content_element.width
        } else {
            translate_element.y = -scroll_bar_element.position * content_element.height
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        scroll_bar_element.onPositionChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hardly write better scrollbar than the existing one, so I made the following code which does the same thing I saw in your example. ScrollBar can be the sibling of a flickable, so it won't take ownership and you can position it where you want. You can even make it rotated.

Is it something that solves your problem?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: main_window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: 'light blue'

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: main_window.width / 3
        height: main_window.height / 3

        contentWidth: repeater_element.width
        contentHeight: repeater_element.height

        ScrollBar.vertical: scrollBar

        // container
        ColumnLayout {
            id: my_column
            width: main_window.width / 3
            height: main_window.height / 3
            spacing: 0

            // contents
            ColumnLayout {
                id: repeater_element
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: false
                spacing: 4
                Repeater {
                    model: 7
                    Rectangle {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.preferredHeight: 75
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                        color: 'red'
                    }
                }
                transform: Translate {
                    id: rect_translate
                    y: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollBar {
        id: scrollBar
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        //try this for fun
        //rotation: 5

        contentItem: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 20
            implicitHeight: 20
            color: "blue"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
        border.width: 4
        anchors.fill: flickable
    }
}
```